# Why my code only running when i add $ in imported variable | Svelte

Tags: variables, import, svelte

please explain why this code
(*storedCAtId is an imported variable*)

`on:load={console.log(storedCAtId.indexOf(cat))}`

give me an error message
storedCAtId.indexOf is not a function

but when I add a $ sign

`on:load={console.log($storedCAtId.indexOf(cat))}`

it runs allright

Comment: https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values

Comment: It sounds like storedCAtId is from a Svelte store. Those are referenced with $, while normal variables are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Svelte store](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store) contents are [accessed via `$`](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values), see also [the respective tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores).